# Bootstrap sub-theme override CSS

Tags: 8, bootstrap-theme

I just set up an new Drupal 8 website. I was used to use CSS injector on Drupal 7, but since the module is not ready yet, and I thought I'd better start with subthemes, I tried to create a new Boostrap subtheme. I used the CDN method, activated it in my admin panel, but when I try to override CSS by creating CSS styles in css/style.css, nothing work. In Drupal 7 with CSS injector, my main difficulty was to find the proper class.
So I tried a lot of different possibilities, copied/paste CSS from original files in Bootstrap. Nothing works.

Have anybody already tried to create a sub-theme with Bootstrap? Did overriding CSS work?

I looked at the CSS file link, it's loading lumen theme nicely. I tried to change h2 color in this file:  `themes/bootstrap/css/3.3.5/overrides-lumen.min.css` and it works...Clearly, seems that style.css is not used...

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention it, but of course i cleared the cache. I also disabled css and JS aggregation.

Comment: hummm, have you tried deleting everything in style.css to test if nothing is changing? Did you remember to switch to the Sub Theme?

Comment: Yes, the subtheme is activated and selected. The style.css comes with nothing inside. I deleted every css i did, nothing changed. Seems that the file is not overriding default bootstrap css !

Comment: May help http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal/theming/bootstrap-1-subtheme-cdn-drupal-8-tutorial-8-article-video

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/panchocadena/cdn-d8-theme/src/master/

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager that the stylesheet has not been added to the page. The documentation is pretty solid on this: [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets).

This page isn't likely to go anywhere, but I'll summarise here. Please go and read the full documentation page though, there is MUCH more there:

> ### The general steps for loading assets (CSS/JS) are:
>
> 1. Save the CSS or JS to a file.
> 2. Define a "library", which can contain
>      both CSS and JS files.
> 3. "Attach" the library to a render array in a
>      hook.
>
> But in the case of themes, there is an alternative to step 3:
>   themes can choose to load any number of asset libraries on all pages.
>
> ### Libraries
>
> [...] a library could just as well only contain CSS assets, or only contain JS assets. Most themes will probably want to have a global-styling asset library, for the stylesheets (CSS assets) that it wants to be loaded globally (i.e. on all pages where the theme is active — usually the whole site except the administration pages):
>
> ```
> global-styling:
>   version: 1.x
>   css:
>     theme:
>       css/layout.css: {}
>       css/style.css: {}
>       css/colors.css: {}
>       css/print.css: { media: print }
> ```
>
> ### Attaching a library to page(s)
>
> #### Attaching to all pages
>
> To attach a library to all the pages on the site that use your theme,
>   declare it in your theme's *.info.yml file, under the libraries key:
>
> ```
> name: Example
> type: theme
> core: 8.x
> libraries:
>   - fluffiness/cuddly-slider
> ```

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for all your answers. Actually the solution was pretty easy...!  In this tutorial (www.wdtutorials.com/drupal/theming/bootstrap-1-subtheme-cdn-drupal-8-tutorial-8-article-video) there is a file named MYTHEME.info.yml , but in the bootstrap distribution in the starterkits->cdn folder, this file is named THEMENAME.starterkit.yml ...Just had to rename it to THEMENAME.info.yml .... And that's all !!!